# Assigning Observable reference to null inside map operator does not make any effect

Tags: angular, angular2-services, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I am trying to create a generic `DataService` with hateoas implementation. 
There's a REST api `/root` which provides all the hateoas link. 
For example,

```
{
    _links : {
        login : {
            href : '/login',
            method : 'POST'
        },
        orders : {
            href : '/orders',
            method : 'GET'
        },
        orderById : {
            href : '/order/{id}',
            method : 'GET'

        }
        .......
    }
}
```

On application load, The `DataService`  should make a call to `/root` api and store the response in an instance variable, say `rootLinks`. It should be available for the entire session.

Then `DataService` should provide a `followLinkByName` method which get's the `href` from available `rootLinks` and triggers a new http request.

```
const rootUrl: string = '/root';
const baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private observable$: Observable<any>;
  private rootLinks: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.ngOnInit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRootLinks().subscribe();
  }

  private getRootLinks() {
    if (this.rootLinks) {
      return Observable.of(this.rootLinks);
    } else if (this.observable$) {
      return this.observable$;
    } else {
      this.observable$ = this.http.get(rootUrl).map(this.extractRootLinkData);
      return this.observable$;
    }
  }

  private extractRootLinkData(response: Response) {
    this.observable$ = null;                             // LINE 1
    let data = response.json();
    this.rootLinks = data._links;
  }


  private extractData(response: Response) {
    let body = response.json();
    return body;
  }



  followLinkByName(linkName: String): Observable<any> {
    let link;
    if (this.observable$) {                              // LINE 2
      return this.observable$.map((res) => {
        link = res._links[linkName];
        // make a http request and return the response
      });
    } else {
      link = this.rootLinks[options.linkName];
      options.link = link;
      // make a http request and return the response
    }
  }

}
```

I have added this `DataService` in `core module's` providers array, 
and `core module` is  imported to the `app module`.

Now there's a `LoginComponent` from `pages` module which uses this `DataService` to login. Though in line 1, the `observable$` is assigned to null, it is available at line 2 when a call is made from `LoginComponent`.

Snapshots, 
1. on application load it invoke `/root` api and once the data is available, assigns the observable to null.
[image]

2.when trying to login, 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `this.http.get(rootUrl)` call is asynchronous are you sure you're not losing `this` context when you're using `.map(this.extractRootLinkData)`?

I think when the `extractRootLinkData()` method is called as a callback to `map()` the `this` context is equal to `window`. So you're executing statement `this.observable$ = null` on `window` which doesn't exist anyway.

You can use an anonymous function instead:

```
this.observable$ = this.http.get(rootUrl).map(response => this.extractRootLinkData(response));
```

... or bind the `this` context:

```
this.observable$ = this.http.get(rootUrl).map(this.extractRootLinkData.bind(this));
```

Also see: [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)